# Why does "Nobody Comes to Fika" not unlock?

Tags: achievements, crusader-kings-3

I started a game of Crusader Kings 3 as a count of Fika. I diverged the culture from Sao in 937 and have been busy spreading it since. However, I'm up to 42 counties converted with no achievement still.

Is there some way to check progress or determine what I'm missing?

The achievement still shows as possible for the save:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you *still* have 42 countries with your diverged culture? AIs like to diverge cultures themselves if they have the option.

Comment: Did you form a duchy before diverging your culture? Doing so would change your primary title.

Comment: @xyldke - I'll check, that is probably where I made the mistake. You should make that an answer regardless because it is informative. Do you have to stay as a count after the fact or is it just the initial divergence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The achievement tells you to diverge your Culture with Fika as your *Primary Title*.

Your Primary Title is not the title you start with but the title that is currently in your name and presented under your traits on the ruler screen. The [wiki](https://ck3.paradoxwikis.com/Titles) has the following to say:

> A character's highest-ranked title is the Primary Title and determines the realm's color and coat of arms. If a character owns multiple titles of the same highest rank they can freely choose which one is the Primary title.

This means, if you become a Duke before diverging your culture, your primary rank will have shifted to the Duchy and would no longer be the County of Fika.

Note that the Primary Title requirement only applies to diverging your culture. To spread it, you are free to expand and change your title.